# How to mention multiple users from a list in one message?

Tags: python, csv, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I currently have a bot that goes through a CSV file with usernames in the format of username#0000 along with keywords for each user. If the bot detects a certain keyword in a message, it will send a message with all users that match that keyword mentioned in that one message. I have been able to get the code to do everything but the mentioning of all the users in one message.

This is the current code that I have but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
mentionMembers = []
key1 = "superstar"
with open('csvfile.csv',) as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    if row[2].strip() == key1: #row 2 of the CSV is where the keyword is located
    mentionMembers.append(row[0].strip()) #row 0 of the CSV is where all the usernames are located
await message.channel.send(f"{" ".join([member.mention for member in mentionMembers])} You're now a superstar)
```

I'm hoping to be able to get the bot to send a message like this
Bot:
@user1#0001 @user1#0002 @user1#0003 @user1#0004 @user1#0005 You're now a superstar.

If I do print (metionMembers) I get a list of all the members that matched that keyword.

Comment: `f"{' '.join(mentionMembers)} you're now a superstar"`?

Comment: This just lists the users but not actually mention them. I want to be able to mention them.

Comment: To mention a user in Discord you need their ID.
The mention syntax is: `<@user_id>`. Example: `<@535159866717896726>`. Therefore I recommend that you store the user ID. Especially because the username can be changed, which makes no sense to store it.

Comment: If I store member ID instead, how would I go about mentioning all user.ID in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mention a user on Discord you need their ID. The mention syntax is: `<@user_id>`. So, instead of saving the username, save the user ID.

Assuming that `row[0]` corresponds to the user ID, you can mention them as follows:

```py
mention_members = []
key1 = "superstar"
with open('csvfile.csv',) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    if row[2].strip() == key1: #row 2 of the CSV is where the keyword is located
        user_id = row[0].strip() #row 0 of the CSV is where all the ids are located
        mention_members.append(f"<@{user_id}>") 
await message.channel.send(f"{' '.join(mention_members)} You're now a superstar")
```

Comment: This is awesome and It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. I changed the append part to take into account possible duplicate user.id. I changed it to mention_memberss.append(f"<@{user_id}>") if f"<@{user_id}>" not in mention_members else None